# Why button click only works in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following button in my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTransfer" OnClick="btnTransfer_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
```

The following code in my C#:

```
    protected void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/physicians.aspx");
}
```

In IE:

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$btnTransfer" value="Submit" id="FeaturedContent_btnTransfer" />`

In Other Browser (FF, Chrome, Etc.):

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$FeaturedContent$btnTransfer" value="Submit" id="FeaturedContent_btnTransfer" />`

It seems to only redirect in IE but not in FF or Chrome. How do I resolve it?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", does it not redirect after it posts back or does it just not even submit?

Comment: Is the button inside of another control or UpdatePanel?

Comment: It doesn't redirect to the page, no matter how many times I click.

Comment: It's inside a DIV which isn't inside anything ASP.net control.

Comment: try Response.Redirect("~/physicians.aspx", false);

Comment: Nope, nothing still :/

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `Response.Redirect` to see if it's even being hit.

Comment: It's kind of weird why it works in IE and not other browsers. It's usually the other way around.

Comment: @Search, please post the actual HTML markup generated for your button element, both for IE and for another browser.

Comment: I added the source code for the button.

Comment: Can you provide a listing of your .aspx file here?

Comment: When you say listing, please clarify...Thanks

Comment: @Search, the markup is identical, so it's a client-side issue. You should look for configuration differences between IE and your other browsers (e.g. proxy servers).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an antivirus application that is avoiding your click. Disable your Firefox or Chrome add-ons and try again.